# What's a good alternative to the included Terminal program on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

My keyboard acts flaky when I use a terminal session on OS X (another question?), so using the command line is often frustrating.  Other native applications seem fine and don't suffer the same problem.  Is there another terminal application that might work better for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the name ssh reveals: it is meant to be a shell application :)

So there will be no gui or what so ever. If you are just pissed using the terminal ... maybe try [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/). Works pretty well ...

Comment: iTerm seems to be doing very nicely and the funny thing is that the regular Mac Terminal is working better since I started using iTerm!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[ZOC](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html) would be a (shareware) alternative.  GUI, tabbed ... overall more along the lines what you see as terminal apps under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an alternative, but you may simply need to set your character set to the correct setting to get it to not be flaky.  For instance if the trouble you are seeing is that your deletes aren't deleting, etc.

Sam

Comment: If you really must know, I have a PS/2 keyboard connected through a KVM to a PS/2 to USB adapter and then into the Mac (you wonder why I have problems?) When I type something resets my keyboard every few strokes and sometimes the locks will all get stuck.

Comment: You should buy a USB keyboard, and get one of the adaptor thingys to plug it into a PS/2 port. They you'd have Mac USB -> USB+PS2 adaptor -> KVM -> PS2+USB adaptor -> USB keyboard. Eventually such a contraption will reach sufficient complexity to achieve sentience. Then it can help you write code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to browse and manipulate files, [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is able to connect to SSH sessions.

When I connect to my server, I still use the Terminal to type commands but use Cyberduck with TextMate to edit the configuration files because using vi is just plain wrong and might actually blow up the universe.

Answer (score 0):

[JellyfiSSH](http://www.grepsoft.net/jellyfissh.html) does a nice job of managing SSH connections, setting up tunnels, *etc.*